# randomizing number of 1's in an array in UVM without using $countones?

Tags: random, constraints, system-verilog, uvm

In UVM , I want to constraint an array such that I can fix the number of ones in an array to 3, I have written the following code using constraint which uses $countones, but how to do it without using $countones ??

```
class class_1;
rand bit[31:0] array;

constraint three_ones {
$countones(array) == 3;
}
endclass
```

Comment: you could create an array of 3 unique elements through randomization (with values ranging from 0 to 31) and use those elements as bit positions of your original array to be set to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is equivalent to

```
constraint three_ones {
int'(array[0]) + int'(array[1]) + int'(array[2]) + ... + int'(array[31]) )
   == 3;
}
endclass
```

### Update

To do this programmatically without any functions, you can create another array with a list of indexes that should be set to one. The size of the array is the number of one you want set.

```
bit [0:255] array;
int countones = 5;
rand int unsigned bitset[]; 
constraint c_bits { bitset.size == countones;
                    foreach(bitset[i]) bitset[i] inside {[0;$bits(array)-1];
                    unique {bitset};
                  }
function void post_randomize();
   array = 0;
   foreach(bitset[i]) array[bitset[i]] = 1'b1;
endfunction
```

Now there is a way to do this without the unique constraint, and without post_randomize, but that's too much work for me.

Comment: Sure, for a small size array we can do that but what if its a huge array like say [255:0]array and we don't want to use any inbuilt functions like $countones, then its cumbersome to add all the 256 elements like you mentioned, how do we implement it in that case ?

Comment: If you cannot use any inbuilt functions like `countones` or `sum`, then yes indeed it will be cumbersome. The comment mentioned by @pulimon is another option.

Comment: I am not very sure of pulimon's method, I did not get it completely .

Comment: I do not get why you cannot use $countones or sum()

Comment: I know I can but I was asked this question in an interview, where I mentioned $countones or sum() while the interviewer expected me to answer without using any inbuilt methods, I was just wondering what was the expectation .

Comment: I assume your interview is over, so I updated my answer